# Why Mockito's verify() counts in when() calls?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit4

The following test fails with `org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations` for no apparent reason. 
Mockito logs point out 2 invocations: first is the one I expect and the second one is in `setUp()` method's `when()` call. 
I do not recall Mockito counting in when() calls, it makes zero sense.
Does this have to do with `Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` or am I missing something else?

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
    private FooService mockedObject;

    void setUp() {
        when(mockedObject.putParameter(any()).firstChainCall().secondChainCall()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
    }

    @Test
    public void foo() throws Exception {
        runStuff();
        verify(mockedObject).putParameter(any());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's counting your setup as invocations since deeps stubs is not supported in the verification API, and complains on the second call

Comment: I can't find the reference to support the claim of deep stubs not being supported

Comment: with deep stubs we can only verify the last mock in the chain and nothing in between. Here you are trying to verify the start point of the chain as defined setup, so this is not supported in verification as deep stubs is meant only verify the last mock in the chain